# PMD error coloring on eclipse project level?

Tags: pmd, eclipse-pmd

Is there any way to color the errors differently in the eclipse PMD plugin?
I know the way via workspace settings, but I need it on project level so I can commit the changes for the full team.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the colour on the project level so you can share it with your team. I created eclipse-pmd and thought about this when I added the preferences for styling your PMD violations. I came to the conclusion that style is a personal preference as different people can have very different requirements. Some people prefer a dark theme over a light theme with respective colours for their annotations. Some people need a high contrast theme or are colour blind and find it difficult to distinguish certain colours. For all of those reasons I implemented it the way it is now.

But I'm open to different requirements. So if you have a good reason that also takes the issues I mentioned into account, then go ahead and [open a new feature request](https://github.com/eclipse-pmd/eclipse-pmd/issues) on Github. I'd be very interested to hear what kind of problem you want to solve with this feature.

Comment: big thx for your reply. added this issue there https://github.com/eclipse-pmd/eclipse-pmd/issues/11